# Version 5.7.1.Final of HibernateSearch complains about ElasticSearch yellow index status

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I tried upgrading HibernateSearch from version `5.7.0.Alpha1` to version `5.7.1.Final`, but it's not possible. I get the following error when running my application compiled with the `Final` version:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException:
HSEARCH400024: Timed out while waiting for for index
'com.example.app.model.journal' to reach status 'green';
status was still 'yellow' after 10000ms.
```

The index status `yellow` is typical in my setting (I think). My whole cluster status is `yellow`, because it is a single-machine deployment of ElasticSearch (for test purposes). So I would like to prevent HibernateSearch from waiting for the `green` status and force it to accept the `yellow` one (the previous version does not do this). Is there some setting that I can set, for example in `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

I found this problem discussed on developer forums, but nobody mentioned the setting name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set this property `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status` to `yellow`. Possible values are `green` or `red`.

> Only operate if the index is at this level or safer. In development, set this value to yellow if the number of nodes started is below the number of expected replicas.

You can find more information in this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html/ch11.html#____anchor_xml_id_elasticsearch_integration_configuration_xreflabel_elasticsearch_integration_configuration_hibernate_search_configuration)